# Find row closest value to input

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling with this problem. I have an pandas array which looks like this

```
               delta_n    column_1   ...
0                10      10        ...
1                20       0
2                30       0
```

Now i have a number, lets say i search for `delta_n=20.5` and I want to select the row closest to the number of delta_n.

My output should be:

```
1                20       0
```

I tried it with `df.loc[20.5]` but as it is not in the pd dataframe it doesn't work.

Thanks,
R

Comment: Is `delta_n` sorted? This is an important detail, so please let me know.

Comment: yes it is sorted

Comment: Then you can find a better solution than the answer below. Take a look at `np.searchsorted`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Subtract value by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html), get absolute values by [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html), find index with minimal value by [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) and last select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
idx = df['delta_n'].sub(delta_n).abs().idxmin()

#added double [[]] for one row DataFrame
df1 = df.loc[[idx]]
print (df1)
   delta_n  column_1
1       20         0

#output Series with one []
s = df.loc[idx]
print (s)
delta_n     20
column_1     0
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['delta_n'].sub(delta_n))
0   -10.5
1    -0.5
2     9.5
Name: delta_n, dtype: float64

print (df['delta_n'].sub(delta_n).abs())
0    10.5
1     0.5
2     9.5
Name: delta_n, dtype: float64

print (df['delta_n'].sub(delta_n).abs().idxmin())
1
```

Another numpy solution for positions by [`numpy.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) and selecting by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
pos = df['delta_n'].sub(delta_n).abs().values.argmin()
print (pos)
1

df1 = df.loc[[pos]]
print (df1)
   delta_n  column_1
1       20         0

s = df.loc[pos]
print (s)
delta_n     20
column_1     0
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```