# find closest row to other DataFrame and get index of that row

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames,

```
df1 = 
    payout
0   0.05
1   0.03
2   0.06
```

and

```
df2 = 
        value
    0   0.0100
    1   0.0275
    2   0.0400
    3   0.0500
    4   0.0570
    5   0.0610
```

I would like `df1` to have a new column with the closest row indicating the index in `df2`. The Output would ideally look something like this.

```
  payout  value
0   0.05      3
1   0.03      1
2   0.06      5
```

[Find row closest value to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587436/find-row-closest-value-to-input) talks about this but only with one input, not an entire column in a DataFrame. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Your output seems wrong.... 0.06 's closest value is not 0.6. Perhaps you forgot some 0s in `df2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with `merge_asof`

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('payout'),
                   df2.reset_index().sort_values('value'), 
                   left_on='payout',
                   right_on='value',
                   direction='nearest')
```